# "He weeps at school." and "He weeps in school." are both alright and the same meaning?

Tags: prepositions

I wonder whether both sentence A and sentence B are correct and the same thing or not.

Sentence A => "He weeps at school."
Sentence B => "He weeps in school."

Thanks.

Comment: There is very little difference between the two sentences. Each is correct. The sentences as they stand, however, could use a context. For example, you could say, "He weeps in school, he weeps in church, and he weeps in virtually any location in which he feels uncomfortable." Or you could say, "He weeps at school whenever he feels anxious about a test he is taking, and he weeps at church when he takes communion." ("Communion" is a religious ceremony which is sometimes called "the Lord's Supper" or  "The Eucharist.")

Comment: Perhaps he ought to change schools.

Comment: ... or stop spilling the free milk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sentence A is primary UK usage, sentence B is primary US usage. Both would be understood in each country.